# SQL: Set variable during Select inside a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I'm trying to set a variable value inside a CTE like so:

```
DECLARE @var INT;

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT @var = column FROM ...
)
```

But I get the following error: `Incorrect syntax near '='`

Is this not possible to do, or does the syntax change when performed inside a CTE?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't set a variable within a CTE, but you can with the _result_ of a CTE: `with CTE as ( select 42 as Lisa ) select @Var = Lisa from CTE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CTE is more like a VIEW rather than a stored procedure. It doesn't seem to be correct syntax - since you can't set a variable inside a CTE - to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @HABO's comment above (I believe) solves the question the OP was asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly assigning value to a variable but maybe you could do something like this....

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, VALUE INT)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1,100),(2,200),(3,300),(4,400),(5,500)

;WITH Variable (A)    --<-- The value you wanted to store in a variable
AS
  ( 
    SELECT  AVG(VALUE)
    FROM @T
  ),
CTE (ID , Value)   --<-- Actual CTE where you wanted to use the value
AS  
  (
  SELECT * 
  FROM @T 
  WHERE VALUE > ( SELECT A      --<-- Use that value here 
                  FROM Variable)
  )
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
```